# Getting data from web service using ajax

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to get data from a webservice using ajax and POST method.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'http://localhost......',
method:'POST',
   success: function(response) { console.log(response.responseText); },
  failure: function() { Ext.Msg.alert('Fail'); },
  jsonData:{ 
      /*Here I specify my request json*/
    }
}
  });
```

The above thing works fine but when i try to mimic the same in EXTJS store it responds with a error
he server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

EXTJS STORE CODE

```
Ext.define('IWM.store.JsonTest', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: true,

    fields:['Name'],

    proxy: {

        type: 'ajax',
        method : 'POST',
        actionMethods: {
            create : 'POST',
            read   : 'POST',
            update : 'POST',
            destroy: 'POST'
        },
        jsonData:{
            /*JSON */
            }
        },
        url: 'http://localhost......',

        success: function(response) { console.log(response.responseText); },

        failure:function(){console.log("failed");},

        reader: {

            type: 'json',

            root: 'result',

            successProperty: 'success'

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: What is your web server? Apache or IIS! Also, post your server side code, specifically return value section.

Comment: Server is apache.

Server properly provides me with a json.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, try to change store config as below.

```
var IWMStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
   // it seems to me you had forgotten model
    model: 'YourDataModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://your-url-address',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'json-root-value',
            idProperty: 'unique-property-in-json-file'
        }
    }
});
```

Example JSON value :

```
// here, ctgMains is the root value, CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID is the idProperty
{"ctgMains":[{"CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID":"1","CTG_SECTION":"HORECA"},{"CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID":"7","CTG_SECTION":"SCO"},{"CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID":"3","CTG_SECTION":"TRADER"}]}
```

**Second Attempt :**
Try to add `headers` property in your proxy definition, like below:

```
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'http://your-url-address',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'json-root-value',
                idProperty: 'unique-property-in-json-file'
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error 'Unsupported Media Type'

Comment: Post your returning json and model definition.

Comment: No :( not working the error still persist.
I'm even getting a error specifying 
'No operation matching request path /ActionflowResponse is found, HTTP Method : POST, ContentType : application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8, Accept : application/json'

Comment: Are you sure to see json value in browser console? If that so, paste this json in here.

Comment: Only when i use Ext.Ajax.Request approach i'm able to see the json.

But in Store i'm not able to see the json in console

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47935/discussion-between-abhijeet-sonawane-and-oguz-celikdemir)

Comment: sorry I can't is because of the company rules. There is firewall restriction.

Comment: Are there any issues in syntax ?
I'm mean this is  way we specify a ajax request,right?

Comment: Actually, I have a same system like you which is working properly. My concern, why you shouldn't use `Ajax.request`? Are there any problem with this way?

Comment: How would I do it ?
Can I send a request using Ext.Ajax.request on a specific url with jsonData in my UI's initComponent() and set a reader for the same url in store to get the response

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Oğuz Çelikdemir's answer, you may need to define a json writer for your proxy.

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://your-url-address',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'json-root-value',
        idProperty: 'unique-property-in-json-file'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
}
```

That should set the json mediatype header (assuming that's what your request is expecting).